# Никак не могу разобраться со Сплитами

Tags: java, строки, split

Дана строка вида: `термин - определение1, определение2, определение3, .....`

Необходимо вывести ответ в формате:

```
Термин:
-определение1
-определение2
-определение3
```

Пример:

```
Ввод:

banana - a, b, c, d, e

Вывод:

banana:
-a
-b
-c
-d
-e
```

Я вроде бы все правильно написал, код работает, но вот выдает почему-то лишние пробелы между "banana" и  ":" и между "-" и "a", "-" и "b" и т.д. Посоветуйте, что поправить нужно?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.nextLine();
    String[] strings = s.split("[,–—-]");
    System.out.println(strings[0] + ":");
    for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("-" + strings[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно тримировать(отбрасывает лишние пробелы):

```
System.out.println("-" + strings[i].trim());
```

А можно поправить RegExp:

```
String[] strings = s.split(" - |, ");
```

Где | - означает "или". Т.е разделять строку на последовательности символов " - " или ", "